# cant install tensorflow in linux server (digital ocean)

Tags: linux, tensorflow, digital-ocean

i bougth a linux machine from digital ocean now i am trying to install tensorflow in venv but it give me an error.please help me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/peter/flaskapp/flaskappenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 210, in _main
.
.
.
  File "/home/peter/flaskapp/flaskappenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 72, in dumps
    return b",".join([b"cc=4", msgpack.dumps(data, use_bin_type=True)])
MemoryError
```

Answer (score 2):

i just upgrade pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade tensorflow with this,and it works for me